# Why is a previously wet light fixture now getting dimmer?

Tags: lighting, water, ceiling, damage

A leak resulted in the light fixture in the ceiling of my laundry room getting wet. Despite being dry now, the light gets noticeably dimmer each time it's turned on. I am trying to keep it off until I know what to do but I sometimes forget and turn it on out of habit. It's so dim now it's almost out. Can this fixture be saved or should it be replaced. The fixture takes 2 standard 25 watt bulbs. The house and its wiring are 15 years old.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the bulbs?

Answer (score 1):

I would replace it.

However, replacing it means turning the power off to that circuit and removing the fixture completely from the wiring after using a tester/multimeter to confirm power is off at the fixture connections. That gives you an opportunity to disassemble the removed fixture as far as you can and look for corrosion and dirt. It might be possible to clean it up and remove any corrosion.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the circuit and inspect the fixture.  You most likely have corrosion forming in the light sockets.  If it is corroding, it is best to replace.

Answer (score 1):

There may also be an issue with the wiring above the ceiling; the copper may have oxidized, causing gradually poorer contact between two conductors. first up: try changing at least one light bulb. As you remove the old bulb, twist it several times back & forth at the "nearly tight" position to help rub the contacts clean, and do the same with the new bulb.

Second up, if that doesn't cure the problem (that was actually two actions, replacing the bulb and cleaning the contacts), there's probably nothing wrong with the fixture itself (the fixture is just a carrier for the light sockets), so I'd want to look at the connections where the fixture's pigtails connect to the house wiring.